# Are static class variables the same as extern variables, only with class scope?

Tags: c++, extern

It seems to me that a static class variable is identical to an extern variable, because you only *declare* it in the `static int x` / `extern int x` statement, and actually define it elsewhere (usually in a .cpp file)

### static class variable

```
// .h file
class Foo
{
    static int x ;
} ;

// .cpp file
int MyClass::x = 0 ;
```

### Extern variables:

```
// .h file
extern int y;

// .cpp file
int y = 1;
```

In both cases the variable is declared once somewhere, and defined in a file that will not be included more than once in the compilation (else linker error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both have static storage duration and external linkage; they have essentially the same run-time properties, only differing in (compile-time) visiblity.

Answer (score 2):

More or less.  Both have external linkage, and static lifetimes.  Both
will be initialized on program start-up, and destructed on exit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

As an additional info, in some programming languages that use non optional namespaces / modules, static class variables can be exchanged with global variables.

In some cases, those other programming variables, doesn't even have static class variables, and you may use global variables, instead.

Some developers prefer use static class variables, enforcing its relation with the class.

Its also a matter of how are you designing your application, even if both features are available.