# Why is this code compiled and linked without an error?

Tags: c++, g++

Isn't the extern keyword supposed to simply 'blind' the compiler? Here are the codes that i can't understand why it is without an error.

```
struct A {
    int a;
};

class B {
    static A x;
public:
    void f() { x.a=0; }
};

extern A B::x; // not allocated.

main() {
    B z;
    z.f();
}
```

As you already know, the static member should be instantiated manually. However, i added the extern keyword, which means it's not actually allocated. It is very weird that it compiles fine!

Comment: I believe that the variable is allocated, it simply is not initialized, which is quite different. Although since you're using a class object, the default constructor may run.

Comment: @ChrisHayes How is that possible? Do you mean to say the extern keyword 'may' allocate a variable?

Comment: @rici I can't see nothing that even hints at `B::x` being in a different CU. Actually the only reason why this code compiles seems to be because it's all in one CU.

Comment: @rici It's in a same compilation unit. Furthermore, I accessed the B::x by z.f().

Comment: @syam you mean, if it's in the same compilation unit and the declaration is not found, the extern keyword may be omitted?

Comment: @isbae93: yeah, i saw that afterwards. You also left out a semicolon, so it doesn't actually compile :) (in that very line)

Comment: @rici Oh, sorry. the semicolon is in right place in my source code. I should edit the post. Thank you.

Comment: cl.exe from vs2008: 1) missing return type in main. 2) extern not allowed on class members. 3) unresolved external. Sounds like a compiler quirk.

Comment: Omitting the `extern` line causes it to fail in the way you expect...

Comment: Why don't you contact gcc devs? As far as I can tell, it shouldn't link, unless there's some small detail in C++ standard I never heard about. Could be a bug.

Comment: Thank you all of you. I should contact gcc devs like @SigTerm said.

Comment: Vaguely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917500/are-static-class-variables-the-same-as-extern-variables-only-with-class-scope

Comment: Sorry. It's g++ not gcc. Thank you again all of you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as an `extern` declaration for `static` member variables! The variable is declared `extern` anyway based on the definition of the class. gcc warns that you can't explicitly declare a `static` member variable to be `extern`. However, both gcc and clang compile and link the code without further ado, clearly ignoring the `extern`.

Of course, with the above code it is also clear that you are compiling with some non-standard mode in the first place as `main()` relies on the implicit `int` rule which was never part of C++.

Comment: I've added -lstdc++. It just complied... How can i make the g++ more strict?

Comment: The `-lstdc++` option clearly has nothing to do with it: this is just explicitly adding the standard C++ library. You might want to compile with `-W -Wall -pedantic`. If you want to reject programs producing these warnings you'd also add `-Werror` or `-Werror=pedantic`.